# What are the differences between Plain, Bone and Flint armor?

Tags: how-to-survive

You can attach bones to armor to make it look more robust. Whereas flint makes the armor look much more aggressive.
Are there any differences besides their looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki:](http://howtosurvive.gamepedia.com/Armor)

> Decorations offer a physical improvement to the pieces of armor they are added to, but do not confer any additional bonuses whatsoever